# Nested Cells TCPDF

Tags: cell, tcpdf

Im using TCPDF for the first time and am laying out some data using cells, the problem is because i am using multiple cells to layout what is essentially one item when the page breaks the items will split up rather than breaking all together.

Is there any way where you can nest cells / multicells in TCPDF??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good blog post that explains how to do this incase anyone finds this post later on - calulates the page dimensions to allow you to work out if you need to add a new page or not

http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/03/27/revisited-tcpdf-variable-height-table-rows-with-multicell/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use HTML tables as on default examples, otherwise you can build custom low-level tables with Cell() or Multicell() as on the example n. 11. Check the official http://www.tcpdf.org website and forums for further information.